# How to use a variable with each_slice() in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, each, slice

I want to use a variable and another solution for each_slice() in my rails view depending on the screen size. I'm using bootstrap, for example I want to display a different amount of item in the same row depending on the screen size.

I usually use the Meteor framework which has handlebars if statements and could do what I'm looking for. Since I haven't used Rails much, I was wondering if there is anything similar.

Bootstrap columns:
`col-md-4 --> each_slice(3)`
`col-sm-6 --> each_slice(2)`
`col-sm-6 --> each_slice(1)`

Here's what it looks like right now:

```
<div class="items">
  <% @items.each_slice(3) do |items| %>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <% items.each do |item| %>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="name item-header">
            <%= item.name %>
          </div>
          <div class="item description">
            <div class="collection">
              Collection: <%= item.collection %>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
              <%= item.price %>$
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Showing different amounts of items depending on screen size would require your server to know the screen size which it doesn't (it is possible but a bad idea in general). CSS is the beast for these kinds of things, all you need to do is create a grid (you already use the bootstrap grid) and just show / hide elements with media queries.

Comment: Yes, but since the items div are different heights and I don't want a minimum height and the bootstrap grid doesn't solve the problem. Also, I can't hide certain items since they all need to be showed... still not sure why you voted this question down.

Comment: I downvoted this question due to it being a CSS question instead of a server-sided question. What a server does shouldn't have to do anything with the layout except defining (render HTML, classes etc...) it and sending resources that use those definitions (CSS, JS etc...). But back to the problem - You're asking us to find a solution to an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This means you explained a problem in your attempt of a solution to the problem rather than the real problem, maybe (and probably) better ways exist to solve your issue.

Comment: I usually use the Meteor framework which has *handlebars if statements* and could do what I'm looking for. Since I haven't used Rails much, I was wondering if there is anything similar. Thanks for your constructive answers.

Comment: In that case I might be conceptually wrong and I'll remove the downvote for that since it would be unjustified, good luck finding an answer!

Comment: Can't actually undo the downvote until the question is edited, apologies in advance...

Comment: No worries, I edited my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that would work even for screen size change, but it includes rendering slice(3), slice(2) and slice(1).

```
<div class="items">
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="name item-header">
        <%= item.name %>
      </div>
      <div class="item description">
        <div class="collection">
          Collection: <%= item.collection %>
        </div>
        <div class="price">
          <%= item.price %>$
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Do not use `slice`, just use plain `each` and bootstrap will do the job.

Comment: Thanks Nermin, sounds like a great idea but would only hide them and render them 3 times. Which could cause to slow down the pages if I have a larger amount of items?

Comment: @RickRoberts I have changed my solution, This will work with only 1 render

Comment: The reason I used each_slice() was all the div have different heights and I can't put a minimum height. Without each_slice() the layout look like crap.

Comment: This only works in ideal situations. Where all the heights match.

Answer (score 0):

Running into same layout problem with variable height bootstrap column tags.

Without using slice to actually close the bootstrap row and column structure at the end between rows the bootstrap layout breaks down.

I am using Bootstraps Responsive tags...you can add more screen size/slice switchers as well...you can run into problems if the screen is manually resized without refreshing but the resulting layout is what you would have all the time without the slicing.

```
<div class="items">

<div class="hidden-sm">
  <% @items.each_slice(3) do |items| %>
</div>
<div class="visible-sm">
  <% @items.each_slice(2) do |items| %>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <% items.each do |item| %>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class="name item-header">
            <%= item.name %>
          </div>
          <div class="item description">
            <div class="collection">
              Collection: <%= item.collection %>
            </div>
            <div class="price">
              <%= item.price %>$
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The other alternative I have used is some javascript like Mosaic Grid Gallery but prefer the slicing as it keeps the divs in order without moving them all over.